# AngularJS directive: how to link templates with actions and passed-in models?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a custom directive - and have two issues. Look at the template below...

```
restrict: 'A',
require: '?ngModel',
template: '<div>' +
              '<button style="width:30px" data-ng-click="clickOnInput()">+</button>' +
              '<button style="width:30px" data-ng-click="emptyInput()">-</button>' +
              '<a style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; width:120px; max-width:120px" ' +
              '   data-ng-click="download()">{{model.inpFilename}}</a>' +
              '<input id="btnF" style="position:absolute; opacity:0; top:0px; right:0px" ' +
              '       type="file" data-ng-model="model.fileUpload" data-np-filereader/>' +
          '</div>',
scope: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if(!ngModel) return;

    $scope.clickOnInput = function() {
        $('#btnF').click();
    }
    ...
```

Problem 1:

The directive needs to invoke functions - functions that will be triggered upon some events from controls inside the template. For example, the two buttons are supposed to invoke a specific scope memberCallback (clickOnInput, emptyInput). I understand that I can create a new scope for just this kind of members by using "scope:true" - and since the directive may be used more than once inside HTML partials, there will be many such "artificial" scopes generated for each use of my directive. So far so good.

However, the body of these callbacks needs to work on elements of the template itself. In the example, you can see that there is an input control with id 'btnF', and the original code I wrote (using normal code, no directives) was using jQuery to "click" on it, via $('#btnF').click().

How do I cope with this when the input becomes part of a directive's template? There may be many instantiations of the directive inside a single partial, so I need separated IDs... I suppose I can create artificial IDs myself ('id' + someGlobalCounter++ ) and maybe inject them in the template whenever it is realized (i.e. whenever the 'link' function is called) but surely there's a better way?

Problem 2:

Similarly, the template contains bindinds to variables (e.g. "{{model.inpFilename}}"). What I want is to pass this kind of variables via a directive parameter, and have them automagically appear inside the directive's realized template. To explain what I mean, imagine that in the end, the HTML partial will say...

```
<div magic-directive-model="model.inpFilename1">
<div magic-directive-model="model.inpFilename2">
```

...and these divs will be replaced by the directive's template - changing {{model.inpFilename}} inside the template to whatever the directive invocation was using (that is, the two lines above would manifest two 'instantiations' of the template, and inside each one the passed magic-directive-model content will be used instead of 'model.inpFilename'.

Is what I am trying to do possible with AngularJS directives, or have I gone too far?

**EDIT**:

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9qcKW5A6yq1hS8OuWTNK?p=preview):

http://plnkr.co/edit/9qcKW5A6yq1hS8OuWTNK?p=preview

...and have significantly moved forward with this. I am almost done, except for one thing:  even though the clear button ('-') clears the bound model and the change is propagated up to the HTML partial (i.e. the {{model.filename}} is cleared), the same doesn't happen for the add file button ('+') - even though the model is updated, the main page is not. Not only that, but if you re hit the '+' button, then as the dialog opens, the main page *is updated* with the filename, but Chrome logs one heck of an exception: "**Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.**" - while Firefox also logs "DOM Exception" of type "SecurityError".

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the plunkr - I was using an ng-model inside the template itself for filedata (which was not my intention, it was leftovers from previous attempts). Removing the  data-ng-model="model.filedata" fixed the issue.